# Shopify PHP API: support for diacritics

Tags: php, json, api, diacritics, shopify

I am using the [Shopify PHP API](https://github.com/sandeepshetty/shopify.php). Products without diacritics work fine, and are added. When I am trying send product with Czech diacritics (ěščřžýáíé), errors are shown:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ShopifyApiException' with message
'Unprocessable Entity' in C:\webdev\www\shopify-api-doporucene\shopify.php on line 32

ShopifyApiException: Unprocessable Entity in C:\webdev\www\shopify-api-doporucene\shopify.php on line 32
```

I am using Wamp on localhost. I tried `json_encode`, but it not working. Does anybody know how can I solve this?

My PHP code (API keys are removed from this example):

```
    require 'shopify.php'; 

    $shops_myshopify_domain = "hyatt-ryan2200.myshopify.com"; 

    $api_key = ""; 

    $shared_secret = ""; 

    $shops_token = ""; 

    // For regular apps: 
    $shopify = shopify_api_client($shops_myshopify_domain, $shops_token, $api_key, $shared_secret); 

   $newproduct = array 
   ( 
      "product"=>array 
       ( 
           "title"=>"Product title (works fine without diacritics)", 
           "body_html"=>"Super Duper Plan", 
           "vendor"=>"Vendor", 
            "product_type"=>"Test" 
        ) 
    ); 

// All requests accept an optional fourth parameter, that is populated with the response headers. 
$senditem = $shopify('POST', '/admin/products.json', $newproduct, $response_headers);
```

Comment: Have you tried modifying `title` to contain accented characters in your PHP? I am presuming from your question that the product name comes from an AJAX operation - which might be corrupting your UTF-8 data. Also check that if you are including UTF8 strings in your PHP file that it is encoded in UTF-8 - check your editor.

Comment: Products is inside PHP file (see above, $newproduct). Ediotor is setup in UTF-8. When I open it with notepad and save it to UTF8, there are nonsense sends thru API to eShop: "Testovacu00ed zbou017eu00ed" (original Testovací zboží").

Comment: Ah right, it uses JSON for server-to-server communication. OK, try `print_r($newproduct)` and output it to the browser (hopefully you have a UTF-8 rendering as well!) to see if it looks ok. What difference does using `json_encode` on this variable actually make?

Comment: Also, that library appears to offer `curl_setopts_()` - I wonder if you can set a UTF-8 encoding option?

Comment: Output: Array ( [product] => Array ( [title] => Testovací zboží zkouším znovu nastavit [body_html] => Body title [vendor] => Vendor [product_type] => Snowboard ) )   //UTF rendering is OK. json_encode is included on shopify.php, which I call via requre.

Comment: I am not sure how can I set curl_setopts_(). Like curl_setopts_(utf-8)?

Comment: Side note: substantial output (like Array dumps) are best edited into your question, so they can be formatted for readability.

Comment: _Like curl_setopts_(utf-8)?_ - I'm not sure how to do that, but it would be worth researching around (debugging, web searching etc). Maybe find the code in the Shopify library that does the CURL op, and add a manual HTTP header in there (I'm guessing `Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8`).

Comment: I try Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8 for shopify.php and not working. Its problem with coding, I am 100% sure. When i try to get information about coding variable, I get answer that code is in ISO-8859-2, but when I change it to UTF-8, product was like Testovacu00ed zbou017eu00ed. I used http://latrine.dgx.cz/autoczech-aneb-automaticka-detekce-kodovani

Comment: What happens when you use htmlentities() on the text first?

Comment: You can also try iconv("ISO-8859-2", "UTF-8", $title) or iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-2", $title), depending on which way you are going.

Answer (score 0):

PREMISE: I start from the comments of @Sarke, so this question will have an answer.

You can try

```
$newproduct = array 
   ( 
      "product"=>array 
       ( 
           "title"=>"Product title (with ot without diacritics)", 
           "body_html"=>"Super Duper Plan", 
           "vendor"=>"Vendor", 
            "product_type"=>"Test" 
        ) 
    ); 

foreach($newproduct["product"] as $k => $v){
    $newproduct["product"][$k] = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-2", $v);
}
```

creating a $newproduct array with ISO-8859-2 encoded values, coherent with shopify server.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using WAMP, try to include or change the PHP.ini file this way:

```
; PHP's default character set is set to empty.
; http://php.net/default-charset
default_charset = "utf-8"
```

Charset problem used to be solved checking end-to-end if every thing uses the same (UTF-8 is the case for shopify). IMPORTANT: reload WAMP after the change.